# Image overlap (RViz and Gazebo world)

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, 2d-image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello people,

I am working with a robot equiped with a stereo camera rig, but when trying to see the image in RViz, I get an overlap of the two worlds, Rviz and gazebo:

[image: image description]

Running image_view to see the image I don't get this problem:

[image: image description]

I am not understanding why, and if someone could help me I would be very grateful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211951/image-overlap-(rviz-and-gazebo-world)/) by [aba92](https://answers.ros.org/users/21911/aba92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2015-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use an image display, not a camera display.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0